# Box shadow is not applied to last item in list

Tags: css, box-shadow

[image]

Shoutout to all the css enthusiasts!
I have applied the following code to each of the blue divs:

```
.lessImports .notesEachContact:hover {
    background: rgba(24, 117, 240, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 4px rgba(24, 117, 240, 0.2);
}
<style>
.lessImports .notesEachContact {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

However only the last one does not show the box shadow applied on it.
Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! it because of `overflow hidden` on parent or give bottom padding of its parent

Comment: Without being able to see more code, a quick guess is the actual shadow is being cut off by the list container? try setting overflow: visible to the container?

Comment: @Frankenscarf Thanks so much! It worked!

Comment: @Frankenscarf Actually now the overflow-y: auto isn't working. So scroll isnt coming

Comment: @PlashGeek then use `padding-bottom:20px` on that

Comment: What @Awais said ;)

Comment: @Awais  Thanks so much guys, it's solved!

Comment: @PlashGeek Thanks so much guys, it's solved!